# Total salary expenditure using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have to display the department name and the total salary expenditure of the department from the Employee table.

```
EMPLOYEE: 
Column name     Data type       Constraints
EMP_ID          NUMBER(5)       PK
EMP_NAME        VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL
SALARY          NUMBER(10,2)     
DEPT            VARCHAR2(25)

EMP_ID   EMP_NAME   SALARY  DEPT
101      Tom        54000   MECH
102      William    43000   CSE
103      John       34560   MECH
104      Smith      56000   CSE
105      Steve      23450   IT
Sample Output:
Department-wise salary expenditure:
IT department, total salary is  23450
CSE department, total salary is 99000
MECH department, total salary is 88560
```

I have this code -

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
v_emp_rec employee%rowtype;
cursor op_cursor is select distinct(dept), sum(salary) from employee;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Department-wise salary expenditure:');
open op_cursor;
loop
fetch op_cursor into v_emp_rec;
exit when op_cursor%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(v_emp_rec.dept || ' department,' || ' total salary is ' || v_emp_rec.salary);
end loop;
close op_cursor;
end;
/
```

I don't know if using `sum(salary)` is right in that place, please review this code and help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by department and then do the sum. Instead of:

```
cursor op_cursor is select distinct(dept), sum(salary) from employee;
```

do:

```
cursor op_cursor is select dept, sum(salary) as salary from employee group by dept;
```

Also I think you should loop the cursor like this:

```
FOR v_emp_rec IN op_cursor 
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_emp_rec.dept || ' department,' || ' total salary is ' || v_emp_rec.salary);

  END LOOP;
```

Comment: When I run the code making the changes you said, it shows an error in the loop statement stating "SALARY must be declared".

Comment: i've changed it add the "as salary"

Comment: Again it showed an error, but this time the first `dbms_output` statement worked. The error is `Department-wise salary expenditure:                                             
declare  *   ERROR at line 1: ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open  ORA-06512: at line 3   ORA-06512: at line 7`

Comment: remove the "open op_cursor;" line

Comment: Ah yeah it worked when I removed both open and close cursor! But how will the cursor work without open, fetch and close?

Comment: the for loop open and closes the cursor for you, and fetches the rows

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so very much for your time and help! :)